# Solve for $x$, given that $e^{3-12x}=0.4x$

Tags: algebra-precalculus

Solve for $x$, given that $\;e^{3-12x}=0.4x.$

I was trying to solve directly, but I couldn't get an answer. What is the method for solving this equation?

Comment: Please include the work you did when you were "trying to solve directly".

Comment: It cannot be solved analyticallly in terms of $x^n, ln, exp, sin$ or $cos$. You will need a numerical method like Newton's Method.

Comment: @Paul, I think the product-log function is used in such cases.

Comment: $x = 0.402248$ using the product log function. From [Wolfram Alpha](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=e%5E%283-12x%29%3D+0.4x)

Comment: @Mourad yes, but I doubt the question asker wants this form. Just a guess though.

Comment: @paul Yes, I want a method to solve this.

Comment: Is there any method to solve these type of questions?

Comment: @ASelvakumar Use product log function

Comment: @aryan beezadhur. I got it. But what ok s the value of w(30e^3)? How to calculate it?.

Comment: @AryanBeezadhur Because you made a lot of superficial edits, and the title you proposed was too awkward.  Just because you capitalized correctly two letters does not merit two points.  You just got your two points though!  Strive for substantial edits, not merely arbitrary tweaks.  That way you can be sure to get your two points!!  And when an edit is rejected, don't be a jerk by trying to do one single tiny tweak, like adding a single character >.  Ain't no stylebook  from which you can concluded that `Solve for $x$ given "fee fie foe"` is any worse than `> Solve for $x$ given "fee fie foe"`

Comment: @ASelvakumar Check [the Wolfram Alpha link I posted, it explains that](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=e%5E%283-12x%29%3D+0.4x)

Comment: @amWhy he said it was a reference to an exam question, so it had to be properly formatted as a reference (with >). And the reason SE is the only Q&A with an ‘edit’ link is to improve posts no matter how trivial, so that’s what I do; I’ve gained over 40 rep from suggested edits on Stack Overflow alone.

Comment: You're free to do trivial edits on your own dime.  But I won't accept a one character edit that awards two points to an editor-in-training.  You asked, I answered.

Comment: @amWhy Sorry but what is an editor-in-training? And it wasn’t a 1character edit, SE won’t allow that. IMO any edit is a good edit if it is an improvement.

Comment: Every trivial edit that is made bumps the respective question to the top of the main page for this site.  That is often incredibly disruptive to users, especially when an insignificant edit is made, and then rejected, and then made again.  So, no, not every single character change is worth the bumping and rebumping of questions in which edits make no significant improvement

Comment: @amWhy what’s an editor-in-training

Comment: When you reach 2000 rep, @Aryan, you will have the freedom to make even one character edits, until then, every edit you suggest requires approval from more experienced users.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Lambert W solution.  Recall: $ue^u = v \Longleftrightarrow u = W(v)$.  So we try to get something of the form $ue^u$ on one side of the equation.

$$
e^{3-12x} = \frac{2}{5}\;x
\\
\frac{5}{2}\;e^3=xe^{12x}
\\
30e^3=12x e^{12x}
\\
W(30e^3)=12x
\\
\frac{W(30e^3)}{12} = x
$$
Numerically, here are a few solutions, using a few of the complex branches of the W function:
$$
 0.2497380098 - 2.495406431 i\\
                  0.2688876910 - 1.974772833 i\\
                  0.2933663762 - 1.456460351 i\\
                 0.3264499677 - 0.9440419025 i\\
                 0.3712495805 - 0.4501671785 i\\
                          0.4022480826\\
                 0.3712495805 + 0.4501671785 i\\
                 0.3264499677 + 0.9440419025 i\\
                  0.2933663762 + 1.456460351 i\\
                  0.2688876910 + 1.974772833 i\\
                  0.2497380098 + 2.495406431 i
$$

Comment: For the real root, $f(x)=3-12x-\log(0.4x)$ is very close to a straight line. Using series built around $x=0.4$ gives as an estimate $x=\frac{2}{29} \left(4+\log \left(\frac{25}{4}\right)\right)=0.402247$